# Add dynamic parameter in global.asax Application_BeginRequest

Tags: c#, .net, global-asax

I was reading this thread: http://sandblogaspnet.blogspot.com/2008/03/methods-in-globalasax.html

I'm trying send extra information in each request (in the `Application_BeginRequest`). Is possible add a new argument at this point before to excecute the request?

The arguments are a custom guid (for tracking usages) and mobile detection.

Comment: Can you add a little bit more details? and what exactly you want to add to each request?

Comment: What is an "argument"?

Comment: @usr I updated the question with The arguments are a custom guid (for tracking usages) and mobile detection.

Comment: @The ZenCoder  I updated the question with The arguments are a custom guid (for tracking usages) and mobile detection.

Comment: No, I mean how are the arguments passed? Do you want to add a query string item or an http context item?

Comment: @usr I need add the arguments to my Http.Context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. A possible approach could be to store that information in the `Items` dictionary of the `HttpContext` class. Here is a sample implementation in a global.asax file from ASP.NET MVC:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    { }

    protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Items["CustomVariable"] = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

This information will be accessible for the duration of the request, so you can retrieve it in your controllers etc. later.

If you are using ASP.NET MVC you can alternatively use a **global action filter** to do something similar and register it in global.asax too.